# Фото-видео запись экрана, драйвера

Tags: debian, centos, драйвер, системное-программирование

Подскажите пожалуйста, когда выполняется снимок экрана любыми программными средствами (программы для скриншотов, видео запись и т.п.), используется ли для этого определенный системный драйвер, если да, то какой и если его отключить, навредит ли он функционированию ОС (Linux: дистрибутивы Debian 9, CentOS 7)?

Comment: Даже в Linux можно вспомнить несколько способов создания скриншота: через фреймбуффер, через libdrm, через X11, через Wayland, для отдельных приложений можно перехватить OpenGL

Comment: Вопрос состоит не в количестве способов создания, а как ограничить или отключить данные возможности создания скриншотов и записи видео в указанных дистрибутивах.